# Google Places API not returning Place Details output

Tags: android, google-places-api, google-geocoding-api

I am using the below given code (taken from [here](https://developers.google.com/places/android/place-details)) to get `PlaceDetails` for a given `placeId` but Google Places API is constantly returning following status.

**Status:**

```
Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 9000, resolution=null}
```

`GoogleApiClient` gets connected. Google Developer Console also shows that 2 requests, for example, have been received and 2 errors have been reported.

I got `placeId` for a given location using this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-placeid-finder).

**Code:**

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
                .Builder(this)
                        .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                        .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
                        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                        .build();

   }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this) == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)
        {
            Log.e("HELLOPPPPPPPPP", "GOOOOOGLE API Connected:  df ");
            Places.GeoDataApi.getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient, placeID)
                    .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(PlaceBuffer places) {
                            Log.e("HELLOPPPPPPPPP",
                                    "onResult is invoked at least: status = " + places.getStatus()
                                            + ", count = " + places.getCount());
                            if (places.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                                final Place myPlace = places.get(0);
                                Log.e("HELLOPPPPPPPPP", "Place f    ound: " + myPlace.getName());
                            }
                            places.release();
                        }
                    });

        }
        else
        {
            Log.e("HELLOPPPPPPPPP", "NOTTTTTTTTT GOOOOOGLE API      Connected:  df ");
        }
    }
```

**Relevant Manifest Items:**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="<MyKey>" />

</application>
```

**Google Developer Console Settings:**

I've enabled 'Google Places API for Android' and 'Google Maps Geolocation API' on the console settings. And I am using Android Key for my application.

Comment: Can you explain what exactly do you want?

Answer (score 0):

This is a method I use to query place details. Alias is a custom model that has a google place id

```
void queryPlaceDetails(final Alias alias) {

    showProgressDialog("Getting place details");

    PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> placeResult = Places.GeoDataApi.getPlaceById(googleApiClient, alias.getPlaceId());

    placeResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(PlaceBuffer places) {

            hideProgressDialog();

            ..do stuff here with results
        }
    });
}
```

double check that your key hash's are correct